# How to create a flip countdown clock widget

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

[image: animation sample]

If anyone knows how to create this type of animation then please help me with it.

I tried various packages from pub.dev but it's not working. Please assist me with this.

any help is appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [flip_board](https://pub.dev/packages/flip_board) package, it offers basically flip boards, ir=t contains also a flip clock and a flip countdown clock.

example of the code you need from it:

```
Widget _flipCountdown(ColorScheme colors) => 
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colors.secondary,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
      child: FlipCountdownClock(
        duration: const Duration(minutes: 1),
        digitSize: 54.0,
        width: 46.0,
        height: 62.0,
        digitColor: colors.surface,
        backgroundColor: colors.onSurface,
        separatorColor: colors.onSurface,
        borderColor: colors.primary,
        hingeColor: colors.surface,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        onDone: () => print('Buzzzz!'),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Widget _flipCountdown(ColorScheme colors) => 
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colors.secondary,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
      child: FlipCountdownClock(
        duration: const Duration(minutes: 30),
        digitSize: 54.0,
        width: 46.0,
        height: 62.0,
        digitColor: colors.surface,
        backgroundColor: colors.onSurface,
        separatorColor: colors.onSurface,
        borderColor: colors.primary,
        hingeColor: colors.surface,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        onDone: () => print('Buzzzz!'),
      ),
    );
```